# pure-specifier on function-definition

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

While compiling on GCC I get the **error: pure-specifier on function-definition**, but not when I compile the same code using VS2005.

```
class Dummy {   
  //error: pure-specifier on function-definition, VS2005 compiles 
  virtual void Process() = 0 {};
};
```

But when the definition of this pure virtual function is not inline, it works:

```
class Dummy
{
  virtual void Process() = 0;
};
void Dummy::Process()
{} //compiles on both GCC and VS2005
```

What does the error means? Why cannot I do it inline? Is it legal to evade the compile issue as shown in the second code sample?

Comment: By the way you've got a superfluous semicolon.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok, I've just learned something.  A pure virtual function must be declared as follows:

```
class Abstract 
{
public:
   virtual void pure_virtual() = 0;
};
```

It may have a body, although it is illegal to include it at the point of declaration.  This means that to have a body the pure virtual function must be defined outside the class.  Note that even if it has a body, the function must still be overridden by any concrete classes derived from `Abstract`.  They would just have an option to call `Abstract::pure_virtual()` explicitly if they need to.

The details are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B_2).

Comment: Yes it should, if you need one. It's perfectly legal to have one.

Comment: But with a body it would just be a virtual function. What should a pure virtual function with a body do???

Comment: @Martin Possibly nothing - if you declare  a pure virtual destructor (for example) you must give it a body.

Comment: @MartinTilsted Not really, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481941/c-pure-virtual-function-have-body.

Answer (score 20):

C++ Standard, 10.4/2:

> a function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and a definition

Comment: This is not normative but taken from a note.

Comment: @Columbo Well, according to §6.5.1 of ISO/IEC Directives Part 2 notes shall not contain permissions at all. While this note clearly contains one, which mislead me. Still modern GCC and Clang don't allow this, do they violate the standard?

Comment: Protip: Read my answer. The note *is* correct, but to 'prove' this one has to show up the grammar rules.

Answer (score 13):

This syntax:

```
virtual void Process() = 0 {};
```

is not legal C++, but is supported by VC++. Exactly why the Standard disallows this has never been obvious to me. Your second example is legal.

Answer (score 4):

Pure virtual functions **in C++** by definition have no definition **in the declaration**.

You second code block is not avoiding the compiler issue.  It is implementing a pure virtual function the way it was intended.

The question to ask is, why do you need to declare it pure virtual if you intend to have a default implementation?

Comment: Pure virtual functions may have definition. Think about pure virtual destructor - it MUST be defined.

Comment: Please enlighten me with the purpose of a pure virtual destructor?

Comment: You make a destructor pure when you don't want its class instantiated and there are no other PVF candidates. Quite  a rare requirement, I agree.

Comment: > why do you need to declare it pure virtual if you intend to have a default implementation?


As an author of the code in question I will answer: the default implementation is provided as a helper for derived classes. They are expected to call the default implementation, but they need to do so explicitly. This is to make sure calling default implementation is a conscious design, and not an unintended behaviour. Kind like "explicit" with conversion / construction. It does not provide any new possibilities, but it can help avoiding mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

This is gramatically disallowed - the declarator that can include *pure-specifiers*, i.e. **the *member-declarator***, only appears in declarations that aren't definitions. [class.mem]
:

> *member-declaration*:
>            ***attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub>
>   *decl-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *member-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub> `;`
>           *function-definition***
>
>            [...]
>
> *member-declarator-list*:
>             *member-declarator*
>            *member-declarator-list*
>   , *member-declarator*
>
> *member-declarator*:
>             ***declarator
>   virt-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *pure-specifier*<sub>opt</sub>** 
>            *declarator brace-or-equal-initializer*<sub>opt</sub>
>            *identifier*<sub>opt</sub> *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> `:` *constant-expression*

The grammar of *function-definition* does not include a *pure-specifier*, [dcl.fct.def.general]:

> *function-definition*:
>      *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub>
>   *decl-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *declarator virt-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *function-body*

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly provide a body for pure virtual function. That function will be pointed to by that abstract class vtable. Otherwise the same slot will point to compiler-specific trap function like `__cxa_pure_virtual` for GCC. There's of course nothing about this in the standard.