# Pure virtual and inline definition

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
struct device{
    virtual void switchon() = 0 {}
};

int main()
{

}
```

I wrote code similar to following and it gave an error:

> pure-specifier on function-definition
>   compilation terminated due to
>   -Wfatal-errors.

When I asked him, he showed me the following quote from the standard:

> A virtual function declared in a class
>   shall be defined, or declared pure
>   (10.4) in that class, or both; but no
>   diagnostic is required (3.2).

I can't seem to understand what it means and I think this somehow is not relevant.

PS: If this is not the relevant quote, please guide me to the proper one so that I can have a better counterargument.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951273/pure-specifier-on-function-definition

Comment: Hmm. Confirms my suspicion. The Wiki link points to Standard C++ 98 - 10.4/2. Here it is mentioned "[ Note: a function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and a definition —end
note ]" which clarifies the situation. So it is not the quote my colleague showed me

Comment: @Nivhus : Yes `10.4/2` is the correct/relevant quote.

Comment: What the quote from the Standard means is that it's an error to fail to define a virtual function which is not pure virtual.  Different but related requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pure virtual function may have a definition (out of class definition). That is completely optional. But what you are trying to do is plain wrong because

C++03 [Section `10.4/2`] says:

> [Note:  a  function  declaration  **cannot  provide  both  a  pure-specifier  and  a  definition** —end note] [Example:
>
> ```
> struct C {
>     virtual void f() = 0 { }; // Ill-formed
> }
> ```

However you are free to write

```
struct device{
    virtual void switchon() = 0;
};

void device::switchon() { } // Definition {optional}

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. Thanks. But I want to know if the quote my colleague showed me is correct or not in this context. Also if it is not, what does that piece of statement really mean?

Comment: What does it mean if something is in a [Note][Note] tag in the Standard? Generally in my opinion Notes are something that are optional to read

Comment: @Nivhus : It means `A virtual function can be defined in the class, can be declared pure or can be declared pure as well as can be defined(out of class definition) {optionally}`.

Comment: Oh. That was confusing to me. I read that statement as if it was about inline definition. Don't you guys also find it confusing or is it that I am new to reading/interpreting the Standard?

Comment: @Nivhus : Yes I also find the text confusing `sometimes`. Instead of reading directly from the Standard why don't you read from a good book?

Comment: My current challenge is to understand this concept and counterargument my colleague's interpretation of that quote. I think the discussion in this thread helps. Probably my colleague is also new immigrant in to this world of Standards (which looks interesting though)

Answer (score -1):

You can have a "pure" virtual function, <strike>i.e. base class has **no** implementation of the function</strike>

```
virtual void switchon() = 0;
```

and **optionally** provide an implementation which derived classes **must override**.

```
void base_class::switchon() {}
```

OR

you can have a "non-pure" virtual function and provide a default or empty implementation

```
virtual void switchon() {}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to know if the quote my colleague showed me is correct or not in this context

Comment: You can implement a pure virtual function (which btw means derived classes must override it, not that there is no implementation).  What you cannot do is place the body in the declaration.

Comment: @Ben Voigt for commenting and other users who down voted: Thanks a lot. I did not knew this, learned a new thing today.

Comment: Your syntax is still a little funny -- there should be no `=` in the implementation, whether pure virtual or not.