# C++ pure virtual function have body

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

Pure virtual functions (when we set `= 0`) can also have a function body.

What is the use to provide a function body for pure virtual functions, if they are not going to be called at all?

Comment: Sorry! I am somewhat new to terms on this forums. I have accepted the answers to what i feeled right. thanks for suggesssions.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Your assumption that pure virtual function cannot be called is absolutely incorrect. When a function is declared pure virtual, it simply means that this function cannot get called *dynamically*, through a virtual dispatch mechanism. Yet, this very same function can easily be called *statically*, *non-virtually*, *directly* (without virtual dispatch).

In C++ language a non-virtual call to a virtual function is performed when a qualified name of the function is used in the call, i.e. when the function name specified in the call has the `<class name>::<function name>` form.

For example

```
struct S 
{
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void S::foo() 
{
  // body for pure virtual function `S::foo`
}

struct D : S 
{
  void foo() 
  {
    S::foo();       
    // Non-virtual call to `S::foo` from derived class

    this->S::foo(); 
    // Alternative syntax to perform the same non-virtual call 
    // to `S::foo` from derived class
  }
};

int main() 
{
  D d;

  d.S::foo(); 
  // Another non-virtual call to `S::foo`
}
```

Answer (score 31):

> "Effective C++" Meyers mentions a
>   reason for a pure virtual function to
>   have a body: Derived classes that
>   implement this pure virtual function
>   may call this implementation smwhere
>   in their code. If part of the code of
>   two different derived classes is
>   similar then it makes sense to move it
>   up in the hierarchy, even if the
>   function should be pure virtual.

see [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=356281).

Comment: Darn... I have the 12th edition of _Effective C++_ and I missed that statement. The one reason, I think, to define it is because it may get called and the default throws which may not be what you want in your software... (of course, re-using code is also a good reason).

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 8):

For most pure virtual functions, you'd be right. However, for a pure virtual destructor, it's actually important to define a corresponding destructor implementation:

- The "pure virtual" is to require derived classes to implement their destructor.
- Your base class destructor implementation is so that the derived class destructors can successfully "chain up" afterwards.

Comment: (I realise this answer is a year old, but I've just seen a link referring people to this question, so ...) Your first point is wrong, a pure virtual destructor does not force derived classes to implement a destructor. The derived class will always have a destructor, even if it's implicitly defined. One advantage of a pure virtual destructor is to make a class abstract if it has no other functions suitable for being pure virtual.